# Is it possible to get a method's name as well as it's javadoc description and write it to a file with TestNG?

Tags: java, javadoc, testng

I'm writing test cases using TestNG for a java class, and sending the results to a txt file. I wanted some kind of description for each method run in addition the the method name and pass/fail so while looking in the output file I know what was run, and I get a reminder of what it does and why I ran it. I was curious if anyone knows if it would be possible, if I were to provide a javadoc comment for each of my test methods would there be some way to get the javadoc description and send it to my output file? Other suggestions are welcome too, this seemed like a really convenient idea for me though

Answer (score 0):

The only way to see the Javadoc is by having access to the source of that method.

As for its name, just use the reflection API.